# NHibernate entity design with a private member

Tags: c#, nhibernate, class-design

In my database I want to save the user GUI settings for one of the "views", as a semicolon-separated string, i.e. :  "1;31;5;411;".

I use NNibernate for this project, and this is the mapping and the code for this specific private member;

**C# entity code for User.Settings**

```
private string _linkConsole = "0";

[DataMember]
public LinkConsole LinkConsole
{
    get { return new LinkConsole(_linkConsole); }
    set { _linkConsole = value.GetSqlString(); }
}
```

**XML mapping:**

```
<property name="LinkConsole" type="System.String" access="field.camelcase-underscore" not-null="true"/>
```

LinkConsole has a lot of public methods for GUI-specific settings, which is toggling the values of certain private members.

When its time to save this settings to the database, .GetSqlString(); formats the string and writes it to the private member _linkConsole , which is the private member exposed to NHibernate & the database.

**Problem:**

When I try to do something with the GUI, i.e.:

```
User.Settings.LinkConsole.SetRightPaneContent(50);
```

This is never stored on the object LinkConsole, and I can't seem to figure out why?
When I set a breakpoint, I get a message in Visual Studio stating:

> Your step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over of a property or operator

Maybe this is a result of the problem, that I'm designing this in a wrong way?
If so, is it possible to achieve this in combination with a private string member?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an `NHibernate` issue. `LinkConsole` is a reference type. If you set a member of it, it isn't going to call the `set` method on the property you got it from, it's going to set the value on the instance that was returned from the original `get`. If you want this code to work, you'd need to get a new `LinkConsole` instance from the `User`, call the methods to set the settings, then set the `LinkConsole` property of the user to your configured instance.

Comment: Sweet!

So this is a overall bad design / attempt of designing something that can't work.

Thanks tom.dietrich!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered implementing a custom IUserType for LinkConsole for use as the NHibernate type?

The use case you're describing is exactly what IUserType is for.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will look into IUserType now.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with how you are setting the private variable that is being written to the database.  Without seeing your code I can't be sure but look at the following article to be able to step into properties with visual studio:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input. I can debug w/ breakpoint, and the problem is occuring before this is written to the database.

It's like the private member never gets updated, for whatever reason.


Maybe there are two different LinkConsole-instances created during this process, which is the reason that it seems like the private member isn't changed on the "final" instance applied to the database?

So, thats why I think its just bad design by me? But it would be sweet if this actually worked, as its quite handy. Any design imrovements (by anyone) would be appreciated! Thanks